# Importing external functions in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm new to Visual Basic and every place I look for the answer to this it seems they assume I have more knowledge than I actually have.

I have a .bas file with a few function implementations. I would like to somehow "import", "include" or whatever the vb terminology is, these functions so i can use them. How would I go on doing this. From what I have seen the closest thing to what I'm looking for is the Imports command, but how would i use it? like this?:

```
Imports "foos.bas"
```

Comment: -1 for no attempt at research

Comment: +1 for I also searched for this and couldn't find the answer either...

Comment: Why import, not just add a separate module for that!

Comment: what does adding a module actually mean?

Comment: @Oded if this is so easy how come there are no answers yet?

Comment: It is very hard to imagine any VB6 programmer woud ask this.  Should it be tagged just VBA?  That might get more pity.

Comment: It is a very "This is my first programming language" kind of question, but why is it not deserving of an answer?

Comment: @rafi: Most of the answers are down to the vagueness of the question. What exactly are you trying to import from where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't import, you add the file "foos.bas" to your project. There are a couple of ways to do it. You can either use the **File** menu, or the context menu in the project explorer. Once the file is added to your project, IF the procedures (Sub, or Function), or the properties are declared as public, you can call them from forms, other modules (.bas files), or classes also in your project. Here is a link to a thorough explanation if you want more: [Working with Projects in VisualBasic 6](http://www.1sayfa.com/1024/diger/vb/ch05.htm).

Answer (score 2):

For a .bas file, you can't use an import like that I think. You can right click on the VBA project and select Import File, but that will just copy it in.

If you had a dll, you can import a **DLL function** like this directly in VBA.

```
Private Declare Function function_name Lib "dll_file.dll" Alias _
         "fake_name" (Arg1, Arg2, ...) As ReturnType
```

Example:

```
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
         "GetOpenFileNameAlias" (openFN As OPENFILENAME) As Long
```

Comment: Import file: good advice. But the DLL advice is bad. You would make an ActiveX DLL in VB6 and then add it to the project references